# rtspsrc internal data stream error gstreamer c-appliaction

Tags: c, gstreamer

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.43:554/stream0 latency=0 name=src src. ! rtph264depay ! queue ! h264parse ! vpudec ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! waylandsink window-width=352 window-height=288
```

I'm trying to write the pipeline as c application. This command runs successfully. But C-application give error `Error received from element udpsrc1: Internal data stream error.`

Here's my c code:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
/* Structure to contain all our information, so we can pass it to callbacks */
typedef struct _Data {
    GstElement *pipeline;
    GstElement *source;
    GstElement *videoQueue;
    GstElement *videoParser;
    GstElement *videoDepayloader;
    GstElement *videoDecoder;
    GstElement *videoSink;
    GstElement *videoConvert;
    GstElement *videoScale;
} Data;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Data data;
    GstBus *bus;
    GstMessage *msg;
    GstPad *pad;
    gboolean terminate = FALSE;
    GstStateChangeReturn ret;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
    gst_init (NULL,NULL);
    data.source = gst_element_factory_make ("rtspsrc", "source");
    data.videoQueue = gst_element_factory_make ("queue", "videoQueue");
    data.videoDepayloader = gst_element_factory_make ("rtph264depay", "videoDepayloader");
    data.videoDecoder = gst_element_factory_make ("vpudec", "videoDecoder");
    data.videoSink = gst_element_factory_make ("waylandsink", "videoSink");
    data.videoParser = gst_element_factory_make("h264parse", "videoParser");
    data.videoConvert = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "video-convert");
    data.videoScale = gst_element_factory_make("videoscale", "videoScale");

    /* Create the empty pipeline */
    data.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("rtsp-pipeline");


    if (!data.source) {
            g_printerr ("source elements could be created.\n");
            return -1;
        }
        if(!data.videoQueue){
           g_printerr ("videoQueue elements could be created.\n");
            return -1;
        }
        if(!data.videoDepayloader){
           g_printerr ("videoDepayloader elements could be created.\n");
            return -1;
        }
        if(!data.videoDecoder){
           g_printerr ("videoDecoder elements could be created.\n");
            return -1;
        }
        if(!data.videoSink){
           g_printerr ("videoSink elements could be created.\n");
            return -1;
        }
        if(!data.videoParser){
           g_printerr ("videoParser elements could be created.\n");
            return -1;
        }
        if(!data.videoConvert){
           g_printerr ("videoConvert elements could be created.\n");
            return -1;
        }
        if(!data.videoScale){
           g_printerr ("videoScale elements could be created.\n");
            return -1;
        }
        /* Configure elements */
        g_object_set(data.source, "location", "rtsp://192.168.1.43/h264cif", NULL);
        g_object_set(data.source, "latency", 0, NULL);

        gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (data.pipeline), data.source, data.videoDepayloader, data.videoQueue, data.videoParser, data.videoDecoder, data.videoConvert, data.videoScale, data.videoSink, NULL);
        //GST_DEBUG=4 gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.43:554/stream0 latency=0 name=src src. ! rtph264depay ! queue ! h264parse ! vpudec ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! waylandsink window-width=352 window-height=288
        if (!(gst_element_link_many(data.videoDepayloader, data.videoQueue,
                data.videoParser, data.videoDecoder,
                data.videoScale, data.videoConvert, data.videoSink, NULL)))
            {
                g_printerr("Error linking fields... \n");
                exit (-1);
            }

    /* Start playing */
    ret = gst_element_set_state (data.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
      
      if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
        g_print ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
        gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
        exit(1);
      }

    /* Listen to the bus */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (data.pipeline);
  do {
    msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
        GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED | GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

    /* Parse message */
    if (msg != NULL) {
      GError *err;
      gchar *debug_info;

      switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
        case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
          gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &debug_info);
          g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
          g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
          g_clear_error (&err);
          g_free (debug_info);
          terminate = TRUE;
          break;
        case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
          g_print ("End-Of-Stream reached.\n");
          terminate = TRUE;
          break;
        case GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED:
          /* We are only interested in state-changed messages from the pipeline */
          if (GST_MESSAGE_SRC (msg) == GST_OBJECT (data.pipeline)) {
            GstState old_state, new_state, pending_state;
            gst_message_parse_state_changed (msg, &old_state, &new_state, &pending_state);
            g_print ("Pipeline state changed from %s to %s:\n",
                gst_element_state_get_name (old_state), gst_element_state_get_name (new_state));
          }
          break;
        default:
          /* We should not reach here */
          g_printerr ("Unexpected message received.\n");
          break;
      }
      gst_message_unref (msg);
    }
  } while (!terminate);
    /* Free resources */
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (data.pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you did not link your source element:

```
gst_element_link_many(data.source, data.videoDepayloader, /* ... */ ,NULL)
```

And be sure to link the elements in the same order as your command line pipeline.